# Facebook Open Graph Movie Doesn't Play in Feed

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I can't really figure out what I doing wrong here. My open graph code, I think it's correct, but it won't play the video inline like I expect it to:

view-source:http://recordmob.com/dev/?{%22track_id%22:%2284%22}

I pop it into the linter on facebook and it comes back all aces?

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Frecordmob.com%2Fs%2FS

Why the heck doesn't this play inline like it should? I'm pulling my hair hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The video source URL is HTTP only - are you browsing Facebook with HTTPS enabled? Facebook won't embed content that would cause mixed content - either include a secure URL for the video, or disable HTTPS on your facebook account - i recommend the former

Comment: Thank you very much!! Perfect. SSL Certificate going in now.